# My Android app does not work on https call at First Run After Installation

Tags: android, sslhandshakeexception

My Android app does not work on https call at First Run After Installation.
And then restart app after https call is fine. Only First Run After Installation does not working.

My App use multiple network class Socket(for tcp/ip), Http wrapped class(HttpClient, HttpGet)

```
**Error Log -----------------------------------------------**
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=91
I/SemDesktopModeManager: unregisterListener: android.view.ViewRootImpl$3@b979a69
I/System.out: AsyncTask #2 calls detatch()
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:368)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:406)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:219)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:172)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:130)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1334)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:700)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:658)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:632)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:621)
W/System.err:     at com.yuanta.mainlib.view.alarm.EventHttpProcessor$NoticeAsyncTask.doInBackground(EventHttpProcessor.java:63)
W/System.err:     at com.yuanta.mainlib.view.alarm.EventHttpProcessor$NoticeAsyncTask.doInBackground(EventHttpProcessor.java:51)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:546)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:427)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:491)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:491)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:387)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:361)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:290)
W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:617)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:364)
W/System.err:   ... 18 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:   ... 31 more
I/System.out: Thread-2620(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: Thread-2620(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
I/System.out: Thread-2620(ApacheHTTPLog):getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
I/System.out: Thread-2620(ApacheHTTPLog):Smart Bonding Setting is false
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Did you add these in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```